# Feature construction widget on Orange 3.13

Tags: orange, feature-construction

I am working with Orange for my thesis with logs and core data; however, since I am a beginner, I am a little bit stuck with the feature construction widget. Ultimately, I would like to combine different features to compare them.

What kind of information should I put in "Values" field with a categorical feature?

If you have any examples on this it would be really appreciated (the ones from Orange did not help me).

Answer (score 0):

As per [Feature Constructor widget documentation](https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/visual-programming/widgets/data/featureconstructor.html), the expression field should return values from $[0, n]$, and the Values field should contain $n+1$ comma-separated labels.